# How to create different iterations of 6 digit integer that is also 6 digits?

Tags: math, encryption, cryptography

I am using an algorithm to create a 6 digit pin from a string of letters(I already have it). I also need to make different iterations of this 6 digit pin that would all lead back to the origin pin which can be used to generate the string of letters.

```
input "FEFOEISUDFRORI"
output 523923
```

some algorithm...

```
 first iteration: 123203
```

then to authenticate

```
iteration: 1 ; pin: 123203
output: 'FEFOEISUDFRORI' // same as original string
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Do you already have the algorithm to go from the original PIN to the string?

Comment: Yes I do. It will convert a string to a 6 digit integer and then can convert that 6 digit integer back to the same string.

Comment: Then all you need is a one-to-one function from 6-digit integers to themselves. There are *very many* such functions (1,000,000 factorial). Do you have any limitations on your desired function?

Comment: I do not have any limitations.

Comment: Hey can help me make one?

Comment: You could add 1 then take the remainder modulo 1000000. You could multiply by 2 then take the remainder mod 1000003 then do it again if the result is not a 6-digit number (since 2 is a primitive root of 1000003 which is the next prime number after 1000000).

Comment: Also note that the length of the original string and/or its permitted characters will have to be restricted.  There can only be 1,000,000 possible permitted inputs, each one mapping uniquely to one of the permitted 6-digit PINs, if the function is to be one-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve this mathematical problem is probably with a rotation. Essentially performing an addition then a modulus, rotation will result in a one-to-one function with a range equal to it's domain.

The example I've shown will rotate the entire 6 digit number or the individual digits of the number.

```js
function rRot(x, rot, max) {
  if (rot < 0) return lRot(x,-rot,max);
  rot = rot % max;
  return (x + rot) % max;  
}
function lRot(x, rot, max) {
  if (rot < 0) return rRot(x,-rot,max);
  rot = rot % max;
  return rRot(x,max-rot,max);
}

function rotDigits(x, r) {
  var pwr = 1, y = 0;
  while (x > 0) {
    var digit = x % 10;
    y += rRot(digit, r, 10) * pwr;
    
    x = Math.floor(x / 10);
    pwr *= 10;
  }
  return y;
}

var samples = [675821, 126421, 678321, 100001, 580127, 999999];

(function () {
  console.log("Rotate individual digits");
  samples.forEach(v => {
    var r = rotDigits(v, 7);
    var vr = rotDigits(r, 10-7);
    console.log(v.toString() + " => " + r.toString() + " => " + vr.toString());
  });
  console.log("Rotate whole number");
  samples.forEach(v => {
    var r = rRot(v, 65537, 1000000);
    var vr = lRot(r, 65537, 1000000);
    console.log(v.toString() + " => " + r.toString() + " => " + vr.toString());
  });
})()
```